# Series notation: Bijection

Tags: sequences-and-series

While proving that the order doesn't matter when calculating the som of a positive serie I got the following problems.

Given $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}^{}$ a positive convergent serie with sum s.
Let say that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}v_{n}^{}$ is the serie that we get when we change the order of the elements in the first serie.

The proof then starts with:

There is a bijection $ \sigma$ : $N_{0}^{} \longrightarrow N_{0}^{}$ so that $v_{i}^{} = u_{\sigma(i)}^{}$ and $u_{i}^{} = v_{\sigma_{}^{-1}(i)}^{}$

Write $s_{n}^{}$ and $t_{n}^{}$ for the n-th partial sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}^{}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}v_{n}^{}$

Choose n $\in N_{0}^{}$ and suppose $N(n) = \max\{\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\ldots,\sigma(n)\}$

I have two questions.

- Why is our bijection from $N_{0}^{} \longrightarrow N_{0}^{}$ and not $N \longrightarrow N$?
- What does $N(n)$ represent? I don't really get it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- The bijection is $\Bbb N_0\to\Bbb N_0$ because $\sum\limits_{\color{red}{n=1}}^\infty$ sums starting from $u_1$ and $v_1$, so you don't want to deal with $n=0$.
- As it says, $N(n)$ is the maximum of the numbers $\sigma(1),\cdots, \sigma(n)$. The function $\sigma$ sends the **first** $n$ positive natural numbers to some **other** $n$ positive natural numbers (for instance, $24,15,1,93,2,\ldots$), of which you might want to know the largest. Since $\sigma$ might not be monotone, you have no other way to state it.

Comment: We only use $ \sigma $ on the indexes to change the order of the elements. But the highest index is always n isn't it?

Comment: @AyoubRossi In my example,  $$N(1)=24=\sigma(1)\\ N(2)=24=\sigma(1) \\ N(3)=24=\sigma(1)\\ N(4)=93=\sigma(4)$$